# How to change the target state in a state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

First, I'm not quite sure whether my case is suitable to use spring state machine.

Here're my case:

I have a big mutable object and a set of logic unit which will manipulate this mutable object in a certain sequence.

For a normal flow:  A.exec  -> B.exec  -> C.exec -> Done

For a bad flow that exception throws from A: A -> Error - > Done  (B and C is bypassed)

For a bad flow that exception throws from B: A -> B - > Another Flow

I guess A, B, C could be modeled as a state while an action could be used to perform real biz logic when transit from A to B.

How can I capture possible thrown exception from A and change the target to another state instead of B?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `junction` or `choice` and define guards for outgoing transitions. Something what is discussed in [gh240](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/240). Then you can catch your exceptions and i.e. store something in an extended state and then from your guards you are free to evaluate different conditions.

Choice is pretty much `if/elseif/else` structure to define which branch machine will follow for transitions.

There's also [deploy sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-deploy) which is modelled with same concepts.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! I'll check the sample.